# Time differences when using VBA Now vs. Now()?

Tags: vba, excel

Need to understand why I am getting time differences.
Here is my VBA code:

```
    Public OHLCArray(1 To 481, 0 To 28, 0 To 3) As Single
    'debug stmt below
    Dim DebugTime As Double

    OHLCArray(1, 0, 3) = Now()
    'next 3 lines are debugging lines
    DebugTime = OHLCArray(1, 0, 3)
    Print #1, "Now()=" & DebugTime
    Print #1, Now & "Debug print line - (just before pushing"
```

Here are the debug output lines in the logfile:

```
    Now()=42527.4609375
    06/06/2016 11:01:00 AMDebug print line - (just before pushing
```

Just so you know, the time of 0.4609375 = 11:03:45 AM; I was expecting Now in the second Print statement to show me this, or to be off by no more than 2 seconds or so.

My questions: In the above example, why am I getting different times? Is there a difference between now and now()?  Can this affect the capturing of time, as it seems to show above?

Thanks for your help.  Karl.

P.S.  Here are the 2 debug output lines just before the lines identified above:

```
    06/06/2016 10:59:34 AM - Skipped ws_calculate routine - CurrentTimeID already processed - CurrentTimeID = 45
    06/06/2016 10:59:54 AM - Skipped ws_calculate routine - CurrentTimeID already processed - CurrentTimeID = 45
```

P.S.S. Here is a link to a somewhat related topic - not sure if it applies to my issue: [Postgres now() vs 'now' in function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34209528/postgres-now-vs-now-in-function)

P.S.S. Thanks Vegard.  Upon reviewing other log files with similar output data, it can be determined that my confusion arose as a result of two errors: a) I did not reset DebugTime to zero before moving the new single data to it (Where do the smaller fractional digits come from when the single is overlaid into the double?), and b) your observation, that the transferring of the single data type to the double data type wasn't useful since truncation of full date data occurred when it was initially moved into my array defined as Single.  I think I will maintain my array as single, however, to avoid doubling it in size, when 99.8% of my array works just fine defined as single.  I can accept the time being off by up to about 2 minutes in the headers of my sheet (when array is transferred to it). I have learned that moving date/time data to a data type of Single in most applications is inadequate.  Data type should be Double or DateTime.

P.S.S. Final:
The logic that ran today (Wednesday, near 11am) with debug statements showed me the following:
    OHLCArray(1, 0, 3) = Now()
OHLCArray element being Single captured the date.time as 42529.46.  Now() however was 42529.45905067 (equivalent to 11:01:02am), and this appeared in my print.debug and print log file (CORRECTLY).  When now was casted, it rounded up to .46.
    DebugTime = OHLCArray(1, 0, 3)
When the array element was casted to DebugTime, additional digits were picked up (erroneously).  DebugTime = 42529.46093750.  This translates to 11:03:45am.  Here is where it also gets interesting.  When I move that array element (42529.46) later to my excel sheet (a sheet that reflects the complete array) - a cell which is formatted to display the number as time only, I get 11:03:45am in the sheet.  So this means that the cell in the sheet is receiving the number in exactly the same way as the statement DebugTime = OHLCArray(1, 0, 3).  Because remember, The array element was 42529.46.   0.46 converts to 11:02:24am.

Thanks to VeGard for all his extra effort.  I hope this follow up helps give you more insight into some of the not so obvious ways EXCEL and VBA behave.  As I always tell my non-computer literate friends: "The computer is never wrong!"

Comment: additional comments added as P.S. in OP

Comment: Your difference is caused by the declaration of DebugTime as Double. Try `Dim DebugTime As DateTime`

Comment: Please don't add more code in the comments. It is hard to read that way. Instead edit the OP.

Comment: jac: DebugTime is appearing correctly in the first output line.  Why is Now displaying as 11:01:00 AM in the next line?

Comment: To jac or whomever: when the array item OHLCArray(1,0,3) is transferred to a cell in my Excel sheet (separate processing), it is displayed as 11:03:45 AM.  So the Array item is correct.  If I were to change Now() to Now in my first execution statement above, could I expect to see 11:01:00?  This is what seems confusing, since the 2nd print line executes after the first one, and yet the 2nd one shows an earlier time.  It seems as if Now and Now() are different somehow.

Comment: I don't have a good answer for that from looking at the code. CDbl converts 6/6/2016 11:01 to 42527.4590277778, with or without parenthesis.

Comment: Is this mission critical? I mean, can't you just use one and stick with it?

Comment: Sure, I could change all references in my code that appears as now to now(), and this should remove any differences.  I was wondering with all the talent here, whether anyone understood why there appears to be a difference.

Comment: I agree that single-to-double casting was not the source of your problem, but it was an observation that proved important to show why single is an inadequate datatype for this purpose. It is connected with the unanswered question of how `CDbl` comes up with extra digits -- I guess it is doing some sort of approximation, but it's anyone's guess how. Single vs. Double also does not answer why one of your `Now` calls returned an incorrect result.. but let's chalk that up to the compiler being tired ;-)

Comment: Single-to-Double lack of precision is not an approximation in the cast, it's a rounding error of sorts due to how floating point numbers are stored in memory. See my updated answer for more info.

Comment: Vegard - you are awesome.  Since you went above and beyond, please read my final attachment to my O.P. (It's ID'd as P.S.S. Final - I'll give you my debug info that will show exactly how right you are.  I'll present line by line.  By the way single to double casting was my issue, and Now vs Now(), and Print statements all worked as expected.  It's the casting and rounding that fools us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any instance where the use of `Single` in the context of dates gives you the correct answer is an extreme coincidence.

To further illustrate why, building on Gary's answer, I've reversed your code so that the array declaration is `Double` - this makes it easier when we want to compare the actually correct `Double` versus the `Single`-cast-to-`Double` which will not be correct.

```
Sub testTime()
    Dim OHLCArray(1 To 481, 0 To 28, 0 To 3) As Double
    'debug stmt below
    Dim DblTime As Double, SngTime As Single

    OHLCArray(1, 0, 3) = Now()
    'next 3 lines are debugging lines
    DblTime = OHLCArray(1, 0, 3)
    SngTime = OHLCArray(1, 0, 3)

    Debug.Print "Doubletime: " & DblTime
    Debug.Print "Singletime: " & SngTime
    Debug.Print "             Date                  Double             Single     Double(single2)"
    Debug.Print "Singletime = " & CDate(SngTime) & " - " & CDbl(SngTime) & "    - " & CSng(SngTime) & " - " & CDbl(SngTime2)
    Debug.Print "Doubletime = " & CDate(DblTime) & " - " & CDbl(DblTime) & " - " & CSng(DblTime)
    Debug.Print "Now()      = " & Now() & " - " & CDbl(Now()) & " - " & CSng(Now())
    Debug.Print "Now        = " & Now & " - " & CDbl(Now) & " - " & CSng(Now)
End Sub
```

Now, let's review the output. I've run it several times, and this clearly illuminates the issue. Observe what happens (or rather, what *doesn't* happen) in the first row of column "Double", which is where we cast a single to double, and compare this to the correct `Double` on the next row:

```
Doubletime: 42528,3991666667
Singletime: 42528,4
             Date                  Double             Single
Singletime = 07.06.2016 09:33:45 - 42528,3984375    - 42528,4
Doubletime = 07.06.2016 09:34:48 - 42528,3991666667 - 42528,4
Now()      = 07.06.2016 09:34:48 - 42528,3991666667 - 42528,4
Now        = 07.06.2016 09:34:48 - 42528,3991666667 - 42528,4

Doubletime: 42528,3995138889
Singletime: 42528,4
             Date                  Double             Single
Singletime = 07.06.2016 09:33:45 - 42528,3984375    - 42528,4
Doubletime = 07.06.2016 09:35:18 - 42528,3995138889 - 42528,4
Now()      = 07.06.2016 09:35:18 - 42528,3995138889 - 42528,4
Now        = 07.06.2016 09:35:18 - 42528,3995138889 - 42528,4

Doubletime: 42528,3996180556
Singletime: 42528,4
             Date                  Double             Single
Singletime = 07.06.2016 09:33:45 - 42528,3984375    - 42528,4
Doubletime = 07.06.2016 09:35:27 - 42528,3996180556 - 42528,4
Now()      = 07.06.2016 09:35:27 - 42528,3996180556 - 42528,4
Now        = 07.06.2016 09:35:27 - 42528,3996180556 - 42528,4

Doubletime: 42528,3998726852
Singletime: 42528,4
             Date                  Double             Single
Singletime = 07.06.2016 09:33:45 - 42528,3984375    - 42528,4
Doubletime = 07.06.2016 09:35:49 - 42528,3998726852 - 42528,4
Now()      = 07.06.2016 09:35:49 - 42528,3998726852 - 42528,4
Now        = 07.06.2016 09:35:49 - 42528,3998726852 - 42528,4

Doubletime: 42528,4045486111
Singletime: 42528,41
             Date                  Double             Single
Singletime = 07.06.2016 09:45:00 - 42528,40625      - 42528,41
Doubletime = 07.06.2016 09:42:33 - 42528,4045486111 - 42528,41
Now()      = 07.06.2016 09:42:33 - 42528,4045486111 - 42528,41
Now        = 07.06.2016 09:42:33 - 42528,4045486111 - 42528,41
```

Note that for all date conversions using the `Single`, the timestamp is actually static for extended periods of time because the datatype can't support sufficient digits.

The fact that casting it to `Double` produces more digits doesn't necessarily make it right -- it becomes slightly more accurate, but still not correct.

So the problem does not seem to be with `Now` or `Now()`! As shown in my examples, as long as the correct datatype is used, they both yield the correct result.

Your first problem, the incorrect timestamps, is caused by the array being a `Single` instead of a `Double`.

Your second problem is something else in entirely, perhaps in your code. Either you are overloading `Now` or perhaps more probable, `Print` is doing something funky at runtime. Try prefacing the `Print` statement with `Debug.Print "Now: " & Now` and then compare the result to the logfile, or better yet, pursuant to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264278.aspx), change this:

`Print #1, Now & "Debug print line - (just before pushing"`

to this:

`Print #1, CDate(Now) & "Debug print line - (just before pushing"`

> Date data is written to the file using the standard short date format
>   recognized by your system. When either the date or the time component
>   is missing or zero, only the part provided gets written to the file.

## EDIT:

As for the mysterious extra digits that appear when casting `Single` to `Double`, this is not an approximation done by the compiler, as I mistakenly guessed earlier. It is a known side-effect of how numbers are represented, an apparently [common topic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) in computer science.

### For numeric precision, use the [Decimal datatype](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xtba3z33.aspx).

MSDN talks about floating-point precision specifically in a Visual Basic context in some detail.

Here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#Conversions

> **Type conversion.** The Double structure provides an explicit interface
>   implementation for the IConvertible interface, which supports
>   conversion between any two standard .NET Framework data types.
>   Language compilers also support the implicit conversion of values of
>   all other standard numeric types to Double values. Conversion of a
>   value of any standard numeric type to a Double is a widening
>   conversion and does not require the user of a casting operator or
>   conversion method.
>
> However, conversion of Int64 and Single values can
>   involve a loss of precision.
>
> The problem of precision most frequently affects Single values that are converted to Double values.

And here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single.aspx

> For example, 2/10, which is represented precisely by .2 as a decimal
>   fraction, is represented by .0011111001001100 as a binary fraction,
>   with the pattern "1100" repeating to infinity. In this case, the
>   floating-point value provides an imprecise representation of the
>   number that it represents. Performing additional mathematical
>   operations on the original floating-point value often increases its
>   lack of precision. For example, if you compare the results of
>   multiplying .3 by 10 and adding .3 to .3 nine times, you will see that
>   addition produces the less precise result, because it involves eight
>   more operations than multiplication. Note that this disparity is
>   apparent only if you display the two Single values by using the "R"
>   standard numeric format string, which, if necessary, displays all 9
>   digits of precision supported by the Single type.

Comment: Thanks Vegard.  I will add additional debug lines to verify your point about Print statement doing something funky.  I'll even add a Debug.Print stmt for comparison purposes, and then I'll report back. It'll be Wednesday after 5pm ET.

Comment: See my final recognition of my errors in P.S.S. of my O.P.  Thanks for your help.  I believe Print statement is working as it should.

Answer (score 2):

Using `Single` as opposed to `Double` produces a truncation of sorts:

```
Sub NotNow()
    Dim s As Single, d As Double

    s = Now
    d = Now

    Dim dt As Date, dt2 As Date

    dt = CDate(s)
    dt2 = CDate(d)
    MsgBox s & vbCrLf & d & vbCrLf & dt & vbCrLf & dt2
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: You are likely wrong in attempting to understand the cause of my output. When the array item OHLCArray(1,0,3) as single is transferred to a cell in my Excel sheet (separate processing), it is displayed as 11:03:45 AM. So the Array item is correct. Also, why is the time earlier when it should be later?

Comment: @KSchempp  As you see from my example, because the `Single` is **rounded** it can either round **up** or round **down** .............. thus the time derived from `Single` will be either ahead or behind the `Double` derived time,

Comment: How do you explain the 2nd print line?  I am printing Now, which is likely stored as double, or more.  My first print line is printing the time when it was stored as single, and yet when moved to DebugTime (double), i capture enough information to get a proper time.

Comment: @KSchempp  even though `DebugTime` is Double, it is initialized from an element of a Single array.......... thus it may be either ahead of or behind `Now()`

Comment: OK, I'm an old COBOL coder from the 80s, and self-taught VBA to myself.  My logical thinking is pretty good though.  You know VBA better than I do, so together we'll get to an AH-Ha moment.  Please review my two print lines.  The first one prints debugTime, and the digits past the decimal point represent exactly 11:03:45, and this is the value that I see in my sheet after transferring the Array element.  It's the next print line that is confusing.  How do you explain a time of 11:01:00?  It is printing Now, not DebugTime.

Comment: I found this topic on this website, but I am not sure if it applies: Postgres now() vs 'now' in function.  It's a bit confusing for me, since I know only VBA.. Please have a look at it and see if relates to this issue.  I'd appreciate it.  Thanks.

Comment: I did as you requested.

Comment: @KSchempp  I reviewed the linked material and I do not think it is related to our problem.

Comment: I found this at MS site: Remarks
the NOW function is automatically recalculated every minute.
Example 1
NOW( )
Returns the current date and time, such as 9/27/1999 12:03:30 PM.
Example 2
FORMAT(NOW(),"dd MMM., yyyy hh:mm")
Returns the current date and time formatted as 27 Sep., 1999 12:03.
Example 3
NOW()+2EW.
Returns the current date and time plus two elapsed weeks, such as 10/11/99 12:03:30 PM.

Comment: Why would Now() be recalculated every minute?  If I use Now and Now() in the same workbook with macros (.xlsm), are there 2 instances of it, possibly explaining the time differences?  I would hope not.  I also have 2 different .xlsm loaded under one instance of excel.  Could this create timer issues?  Hmmm.

Comment: @KSchempp  I have never encountered `=NOW()` as a spreadsheet formula automatically re-calculating unless the worksheet recalculates.

Comment: I agree with you.  It's an archived link at the MS site.  Note sure why the author made that statement.

Comment: See my final recognition of my errors in P.S.S. of my O.P. Thanks for your help. I believe Print statement is working as it should.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between Now and Now(). the Difference in your example is because OHLCarray is declared as single. When I declare evrything as double the times are the same:

Now()=42528.3594907407
42528.3594907407Debug print line - (just before pushing

(BTW if you want accurate timings use windows api calls to the high-res timer)

```
Sub lg()
Dim OHLCArray(1 To 481, 0 To 28, 0 To 3) As Double
    'debug stmt below
    Dim DebugTime As Double

    OHLCArray(1, 0, 3) = Now()
    'next 3 lines are debugging lines
    DebugTime = OHLCArray(1, 0, 3)
    Debug.Print "Now()=" & DebugTime
    Debug.Print CDbl(Now) & "Debug print line - (just before pushing"
End Sub
```

Comment: See my final recognition of my errors in P.S.S. of my O.P. Thanks for your help. I believe Print statement is working as it should.