# Type Double rounding error in VBA

Tags: excel, macros, double, rounding, vba

I have a macro that iterates 5 times and uses a double to store a value throughout each loop. The problem is that the double is not storing the value to enough decimal places:

> 65,314 - 6683.25533205254 = 58,630.7446694746

This is the kind of accuracy I need but the double is simply storing the answer as 58,630.7447 therefore I am losing accuracy through each iteration. Here is the code:

```
    Dim eg As Double

i = 2

Do Until i = lngRow + 1
    If Cells(i, coltemp) < 0 Then
        eg = Cells(i, coltemp2) + Cells(i, col3)
        Cells(i, col4) = eg
    Else
        Cells(i, col4) = Cells(i, coltemp2)
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

Can anyone see a way around this? Any way to make a double more precise or even a different data type altogether? Thanks.

Comment: A Double should be capable of that level of precision. What's your actual code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your cells are formatted as currency, which would explain the 4DP precision. Use the `Value2` property:

```
Do Until i = lngRow + 1
    If Cells(i, coltemp).Value2 < 0 Then
        eg = Cells(i, coltemp2).Value2 + Cells(i, col3).Value2
        Cells(i, col4).Value2 = eg
    Else
        Cells(i, col4).Value2 = Cells(i, coltemp2).Value2
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37674323/4604845) here, specifically the latter half of it.

The short answer: use the [Decimal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xtba3z33.aspx) data type.

> Holds signed 128-bit (16-byte) values representing 96-bit (12-byte)
>   integer numbers scaled by a variable power of 10. The scaling factor
>   specifies the number of digits to the right of the decimal point; it
>   ranges from 0 through 28. With a scale of 0 (no decimal places), the
>   largest possible value is +/-79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335
>   (+/-7.9228162514264337593543950335E+28). With 28 decimal places, the
>   largest value is +/-7.9228162514264337593543950335, and the smallest
>   nonzero value is +/-0.0000000000000000000000000001 (+/-1E-28).

Comment: I've tried defining as a Decimal and it throws me a compile error. I read somewhere that you have to define as a variant first, however this still goes to the same precision as a Double. I've added my code to the question now.

Comment: You can't `Dim` to decimal in VBA, but you can cast to it. `someVariable = CDec(346345.63463)`